# How to find all handlebar partials in a file using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

The expression I have been using works in regExr but when I run my code in node it just returns one partial instead of an array of partials.

My Node file

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function() {
  fs.readFile('text.txt', 'UTF8', function(err, contents) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var re = /({{> (\w*)}})/g;
    var myArray = re.exec(contents);

    console.log(myArray);
  });
}();
```

Text.txt

```
{{> test}}

{{> test2}}

{{> test3}}
```

My returned result is just `{{> test}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.exec()` you need to call it in a loop until it returns `null` to get all matching results. To simply get the matches in an array use `.match` on the contents instead:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function() {
  fs.readFile('text.txt', 'UTF8', function(err, contents) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var re = /({{> (\w*)}})/g;
    var myArray = contents.match(re);

    console.log(myArray);
  });
}();
```

Comment: What if you wanted your partial to be {{> test-1}}. The expression above does not work for that senario.

Comment: This is a different question, but you just have to change the `(\w*)` into something that matches your names `([^}]+)` for example if you want to match anything.